# Apache can't be accessed externally

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, vtiger

I have ubuntu server with pre-installed apache2, mssql, php5. I install vTiger CRM and it available on my localhost and internal IP.
But i can't reach it using my external IP. I checked all setups on my router and it seems to be ok.

This is my **netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN**

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 10.1.0.4:16001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:29131         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:3a:b3:0e:a1  
          inet addr:10.1.0.4  Bcast:10.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:3aff:feb3:ea1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10379793 (10.3 MB)  TX bytes:7676670 (7.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:208812 (208.8 KB)  TX bytes:208812 (208.8 KB)
```

**apache2 ports.conf**

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no port 80 enabled with IP V4.
Are you accessing that using IP V6?
Check that and it should have something like 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: thanks for your answer! tell me please how i can check that?

Comment: It should come with the same command netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN.
There must be some process with IP V4 listening to port 80 or you can modify the same here netstat -ntlp | grep ':80'

Comment: as i understand i need to config apache2 to listen port 80?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106502/apache2-does-not-run-on-ipv4-tcp-port it seems that port 80 should work for IP V4 and IP V6